# Create a Checkbox

Tags: code-golf, interactive

Write a program that creates a two-state [checkbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox) that people can interact with using a mouse.

Specifically, your program should achieve all of the following:

1. Have a 8×8 pixel (or larger if desired) region of the screen that is the clickable area of the checkbox. Henceforth this region is simply called the checkbox.
2. When the mouse cursor is moved within the checkbox and the default* mouse button is pressed, the checkbox should toggle states.
   Checked becomes unchecked. Unchecked becomes checked.
3. The checkbox should not move when it is toggled.
4. In the checked state, the checkbox may be any colors.
5. In the unchecked state, the checkbox may be any colors **as long as at least 16 pixels are visually distinct from the checked state**.
6. In a single program instance, all checked states should be visually identical to one another and all unchecked states should be visually identical to one another.
7. Don't end the program until it's explicitly terminated (e.g. via exit button or Alt+F4), so a user can click the checkbox as much as they want.

<sup>*You may assume the default mouse button is always left click, but it's also fine to use the default as defined by mouse software or the OS, which may not actually be left click depending on the user.</sup>

## Notes

- It does not matter what is outside of your checkbox region.  It could just be the desktop. It could be a portion of a console that changes on every toggle.
- It does not matter what state your checkbox starts in.
- The checkbox region may have any dimensions at or above 8×8 pixels. It need not be square.
- You may make minor allowances for settings that are out of your control such as console font size, browser zoom, monitor resolution, etc. As long your program works in a reasonable test setting it should be valid.
- If your program opens a window, you may assume it has been dragged to an appropriate location on the screen if necessary (e.g. top left corner).
- You may use markup languages such as HTML or other languages [we usually don't consider](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3610/26997) as full-fledged programming languages.
- Your checkbox *must* be be toggleable using the default mouse button. It's alright if it also toggles for other forms of input (e.g. right mouse button), **with the exception of mouse motion**. i.e. the state should not change if the mouse is merely moved within the checkbox.
- **Screenshots of your checkbox in action are highly encouraged!**

## Scoring

The shortest code in bytes wins.

## Example

A canonical HTML example in 23 bytes.

```html
<input type="checkbox">
```

For me in Google Chrome, this makes a 12×12 pixel checkbox and about 30 pixels clearly change between checked and unchecked states.

I make the allowance that browser zoom is at 100%.

Comment: Can the checkbox cover the entire screen?

Comment: @KritixiLithos Yes, that would be valid.Though note that you may, if desired, count a particular 8x8 region as the official checkbox, even if a larger region works.

Comment: @Helka Homba - is it allowed for an app to display other controls, aside the checkbox itself ?

Comment: Is it OK for the checkbox to toggle on other sorts of input? (For example, is a solution correct if the checkbox toggles on any sort of user input, regardless of whether it's a mouse click, a mouse movement, or a keypress? It'd toggle on a mouse click, but it'd toggle on other stimuli too.)

Comment: Would touching a touchscreen instead of using a mouse be acceptable?

Comment: *When the mouse cursor is moved within the checkbox and the default mouse button is pressed* Can we also toggle if the user clicks outside the checkbox or with another mouse button apart from the left one?

Comment: @zeppelin "It does not matter what is outside of your checkbox region. It could just be the desktop. It could be a portion of a console that changes on every toggle." So, as long as the checkbox is there, it doesn't matter what else is.

Comment: @ais523 / 12Me21 / Dennis it's ok if other forms of input, except for mouse-motion, (like keypress/touch/right click) also toggle the checkbox, whether inside the region or outside, as long as the default mouse button works to toggle the checkbox as well.

Comment: Finally a task where KV lang, or any lang that creates an instance from `checkbox` string just wins. But I fear there's some character/byte in some gibberish that does the same thing and if not, someone will write it just to solve this. :D

Comment: Can the checkbox display after another region is clicked? For example, the program runs, part of what displays is a button, upon clicking the button, a checkbox which satisfies all other conditions is visible.

Comment: @briantist No, I think the checkbox should show up right away

Comment: May we abuse external programs which has checkboxes?

Comment: _"It does not matter what state your checkbox starts in."_ Does it matter if the initial state is distinct from the checked _and_ the unchecked state?

Comment: Wait, does the checkbox *have* to be on the screen? 'cause we already have one on the keyboard!

Answer (score 33):

### Mathematica, 10 bytes

```
Checkbox[]
```

Assumes Mathematica's [notebook environment](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7844/8478).

The two states look like this:

[image]

Comment: Sure. Mathematica cheats again.

Comment: It's funny how the comment has more upvotes than the answer

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek it's funny how the answer has any upvotes at all...

Answer (score 32):

### HTML, 20 bytes

Don't know how valid this will be as an answer. HTML requires the tag to be closed to legally validate, but modern browsers will automatically close them so it's executable.

```html
<input type=checkbox
```

Comment: I was looking at this as an option earlier (without quotes) but completely missed the closing `>`. +1 and valid IMHO.

Comment: On this site, languages are defined by their implementation, so this seems fine to me.

Comment: Thanks @JohnGowers , I've been wondering about the definition of how much abuse is acceptable.

Comment: I think you need to be more specific about which "modern browsers". It doesn't work in FF for me.

Answer (score 29):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), <s>67</s> <s>55</s> <s>50</s> <s>35</s> <s>32</s> 31 bytes

```bash
:()(read -p$[i^=1]›?9h -sn6
:)
```

The code contains a CR byte (first newline) and a CSI byte (small right angle bracket with the Windows-1252 encoding). It requires xterm (or equivalent) and the ISO-8859-1 encoding (or similar).

The code defines a function named `:`, which alternately displays a white **1** or **0** in a black rectangle. There are exactly 24 differing pixels with xterm's default settings. ([proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xovkr.png))

For an older version that toggles the color of the entire terminal, check [revision 10](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/109186/10) of this answer.

*Thanks to @ais523 for suggesting* xterm, *which saves 4 bytes!*

#### How it works

`:(...)` creates a function named `:` that executes `...`.

The *read* command does the actual magic.

- `-p` specifies an input prompt, which is printed to STDOUT.

  - `$[i^=1]` is an arithmetic expansion which XORs the variable **i** with **1**. **i** may initially be unset; when this occurs, it will be treated as **0**.
  - The carriage return places the cursor back at the beginning of the line.
  - `›?9h` captures the mouse in supported terminals. Each click will send six characters to the terminal, namely `←[Mbxy`, where `←` represents the ESC byte (**0x1b**). `←[` indicates an escape sequence, `M` the mouse, `b` the button (**0x20** + the button number), `x` the **x** coordinate of the click (**0x20** + coordinate), and `y` the **y** coordinate.
  - `-sn6` makes *read* silent (the mouse input won't be echoed to STDERR) and stops after reading exactly 6 bytes. It saves the input in the **REPLY** variable, but we're not interested in the output it produces.

Finally, once *read* finishes (after exactly one mouse click), `:` recursively calls itself, entering an infinite loop.

#### Creation and invocation

```bash
$ echo $':()(read -p$[i^=1]\r\x9b?9h -sn6\n:);:' > checkbox.sh
$ xxd -c 17 -g 1 checkbox.sh
0000000: 3a 28 29 28 72 65 61 64 20 2d 70 24 5b 69 5e 3d 31  :()(read -p$[i^=1
0000011: 5d 0d 9b 3f 39 68 20 2d 73 6e 36 0a 3a 29 3b 3a 0a  ]..?9h -sn6.:);:.
$ LANG=en_US xterm -e bash checkbox.sh
```

#### Output

[image: screencast]

Comment: I was working on a similar solution to this myself (although in a different language, forcing me to give up because I couldn't find a way to take input without a newline). A likely improvement: change `1000h` to `9h` (the difference is that `1000h` handles both mouse press and release, and `9h` handles only mouse release). This might or might not need changes elsewhere in the code.

Comment: @ais523 I tried that, but at least my terminal emulator (Konsole) doesn't seem to support it. Do you know one that does?

Comment: `gnome-terminal` seems to work, that's what I was using for testing (edit: but I don't think it supports a 1-byte CSI). `xterm` should also work and might be easier to install if you have a KDE system. (I just tested this myself; it works with `\x1b[` but not with `\x9b` for some reason, possibly related to my stty settings rather than to the terminal itself.)

Comment: @ais523 I do have xterm. I'll check when I'm back at my PC.

Comment: @ais523 xterm works like a charm!  I'll update asap, with a few more byte savings. To use the CSI byte, you have to set the terminal to Latin-1. `LANG=en_US` should do the trick. Gnome terminal might require additional settings.

Comment: @ais523 xterm saved 4 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: I love  how it becomes `:)` from `:(` by the end

Answer (score 25):

## GitHub Flavored Markdown - 6 bytes

```
- [ ]
```

(There is a trailing space)

In a gist :
[image: check/not check]

Comment: Sure this matches the 2nd half of the 1st sentence, “Write a program that creates a two-state checkbox _that people can interact with using a mouse_.”?

Comment: Yes, if you paste it in a gist and create the gist (for "compilation") you will be able to interact with it.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks @Ax31. I never used gists.

Comment: I would not have expected "Github Flavoured Markdown".

Answer (score 24):

## HTML + JavaScript, <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 25 chars

```html
<p onclick=innerHTML^=1>0
```

Comment: `this` is implicit and can be removed. Also, `innerHTML` is shorter.

Comment: @Dennis, strange with this... Thank you.

Comment: +1 for not using the `<input>` element

Answer (score 22):

## Processing, <s>78</s> <s>66</s> <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 61 bytes

*2 bytes saved thanks to @TuukkaX by using `-a%2` instead of `a%2*-1`*

*2 bytes saved thanks to @TuukkaX by using `a=-a`*

```processing
int a=1;void draw(){background(a);}void mousePressed(){a=-a;}
```

The checkbox alternates between being black and white.

#### Explanation

```processing
int a=1;                   //the variable that contains the state of the checkbox
void mousePressed(){a=-a;} //if the mouse is pressed, change the sign of a
```

Now there are many other alternatives like using an if-statement to process this, but then it gets weird and constantly changes the background while the mouse is being pressed. I first tried `mouseButton`, but then I would need more conditions and more code that will just end up much more verbose.

Now for `mousePressed()` to be called forever (otherwise it would just stop after the program has just started), we need a `draw()` function.

```processing
void draw(){               //loop infinitely
  background(a);           //set the sketch's background to -a%2
  //if a ==  1, the background colour is set to almost black
  //if a == -1, the background colour is set to white
}
```

[image]

---

A smaller checkbox would be 90 bytes (the checkbox is in the top left corner, so we can remove some mouse conditions):

```processing
int a=1;void draw(){fill(a);rect(0,0,8,8);}void mousePressed(){if(mouseX<9&mouseY<9)a=-1;}
```

Comment: Clever use of how Processing accept single integers as grayscale colours!

Comment: @FlipTack It seems that white can also be expressed as `fill(-1)`

Comment: I have an idea. Initialize `a` to 1 instead of 0. Change `a++` to `a=-a`, which makes `-a%2` just `a`. This will toggle `a` between 1 and -1. I don't know what color 1 produces though.

Comment: @TuukkaX Yup it works. `color(1)` produces `#010101` which is very close to black

Answer (score 22):

## Unix Shell (+x11-apps), 3 bytes

**Disclaimer**

The answer below is boring, borderline and "feels cheating" (at least to me).

Yet, it does not seem to violate any of the challenge rules "as written", or "default loopholes", so I'm posting it.

(If you can point a specific rule it breaks, please comment on !)

**Golfed**

```bash
xgc
```

> The  xgc  program  demonstrates various features of the X graphics primitives.

The *xgc* screen is actually filled with various checkboxes:

[image]

and "sticky buttons" (which qualify as checkboxes, under this challenge rules):

[image]

Answer (score 18):

## [AHK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey), 25 bytes

```
Gui,Add,Checkbox
Gui,Show
```

Output -

[image: Mouse pointer is not captured in this gif]

Answer (score 17):

## Scratch, 2 blocks

[image]

Put this script in the default sprite (which comes with 2 costumes)

Comment: Online demo: https://phosphorus.github.io/app.html?id=143917094&full-screen=false

Answer (score 14):

### Python REPL, 45 bytes

```
from tkinter import*
Checkbutton(Tk()).pack()
```

Comment: I don't participate in CG nor do I often read these posts. However it really surprises me that you are allowed to use external modules. Isn't that cheating? I don't know how many bytes the Tk source code is, but really shouldn't these bytes be added to your byte count?

Comment: @Krazor `tkinter` is a standard library for Python (but even if it wasn't I'd only have to declare Python REPL + tkinter). This means that I can use it's features by simply importing it. The penalty you suggest is similar to asking users to include in the byte count the number of bytes in the source of the language you're writing in. Here we allow any language or module to compete as long as it was written and published publicly before the challenge was posted.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 14):

## [GeoGebra](https://www.geogebra.org/), 10 bytes

```
Checkbox[]
```

Entered into the input bar.

Here is a gif of the execution:

[image: Program execution]

Comment: Whoah, GeoGebra. I remember that. It's been a while.

Comment: I know this is off-topic but do you go to Waterloo Collegiate Institute? Just out of curiosity, based on your name. I'm not a stalker don't worry :)

Answer (score 13):

## Tcl/Tk, 21 byte

**Golfed**

```
grid [checkbutton .c]
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

## HTML with JavaScript - <s>136</s> <s>124</s> <s>120</s> <s>115</s> <s>113</s> <s>111</s> <s>109</s> 79 bytes

```html
<p style=height:20;border:solid onClick=t=this;t.innerHTML=(t.e=!t.e)?'x':''>
```

-2 with thanks to @KritixiLithos

Reduced to 79 after some fantastic golfing from @Jan. Although the new version fits the requirements I have kept the old version for professional pride reasons.

While it is perfectly valid to use built-ins, I thought it was more fun to create my own from scratch. Tested with Chrome and Firefox. `border:solid` is there for IE compatibility but I don't know if it is actually needed in newer IE versions - I don't have IE available to test.

The `px` in the height is there for the benefit of "Run code snippet" so is not included in the "real" byte count. It works fine in the browser without it.

```html
<p style=height:20px;border:solid onClick=t=this;t.innerHTML=(t.e=!t.e)?'x':''>
```

Previous version:

```html
<p id=d style="width:20px;height:20px;border:solid 1px"onClick="d.innerHTML=d.innerHTML=='x'?'':'x'"align=center>
```

Comment: Can you do `id=d` to remove `d=this`?

Comment: @KritixiLithos - Indeed I can. Thanks and well spotted :)

Comment: You don't need to set the width, the rules say it can be any dimensions. 
If you store the state on a property on `this` you'll save setting the id. 
If you store `this` in a property you'll save a few bytes.
The `align` is unnecessary. 
Since there are no spaces in the attribute strings, you don't need the quotes. 

`<p style=height:20px;border:solid onClick=t=this;t.innerHTML=(t.e=!t.e)?'x':''>` 79 bytes

Comment: @Jan - Thanks! The width bit is my own professional pride. If I don't set it it looks ugly and since this answer is never going to win and was just posted as an alternative I'll probably leave it there. Other than that some great hints. Many thanks. Will update tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks @Easterly. Updated the code but forgot the other bits. It's getting late.

Comment: The task is to make the code as short as possible. If that means abusing the language or the requirements, that's what you should do. I can relate to the feeling though

Comment: @Jan - Understood. I should stop thinking so much like a programmer and more like a golfer ;-) Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, for the challenge you could just skip the styling entirely in favour of just using a `body` element, making the entire application clickable. It won't work inside a code snippet, but you could post a jsbin instead like https://jsbin.com/pivumowuyi/edit?html,output

Comment: Now that's getting really smart :-) Feel free to post as your own answer. You will get +1 from me. I'm going to leave this as it is now.

Comment: No, it's really just an extension of your answer. The logic is still the same, it's just been shifted.

Comment: Still ok by me if you mention my answer ;-) "Improvement of the answer from ElPedro with permission" would work for me.

Comment: Why use `'x'` which is 3 bytes. Why not use `8` which is one byte. Rules don't say the check has to be anything specific. @Jan

Comment: @Jan Also instead of saying `t.e=!t.e` you can just say `t.e^=1` and knock off 2 more bytes

Comment: @Jan Also you don't need the closing tag `>` you can simply leave it off for another saved byte :D (As referenced in your main answer +1'd btw)

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw at OP's suggestion I posted my own version of this at http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109155/create-a-checkbox/109289#109289

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw - Thanks for the hints. I think Jan's solution is way ahead of any improvements I can make on this now :)

Comment: You can use a `<fieldset>` and remove all styling

Comment: You can remove `;border:solid` and still meet the challenge requirements: `<p style=height:20px onClick=t=this;t.innerHTML=(t.e=!t.e)?'x':''>` (66 bytes). The works in IE 10 & 11, just like the original code does.

Answer (score 10):

## Minecraft 1.0.0, 1 byte

A lever in Minecraft meets all the criteria for a check box. This answer is only valid for older versions of the game where punching a lever still toggles it.

[image]

[Scored using @Connor O'Brien's suggested byte count.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/7397/44713)

Comment: A difference of 3 between two answers hardly makes or breaks a consensus, but considering that Conor's answer is quite controversial (currently at **+24/-10**) and that [the accepted answer](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/9529/12012) is overwhelmingly well received (**+17/-0**), I think the latter should be used to score Minecraft answers.

Comment: However there are no structure blocks in Minecraft 1.0.0

Comment: It's one `n` in Conor, btw :)

Comment: Or you could rebind the left and right mouse buttons in any newer version to make it valid ;D

Comment: @ConorO'Brien Isn't that `1 block`? Why `1 byte`? I don't think mc stores every block as one byte...

Answer (score 10):

### Any version of Windows command line, 3 bytes

**(cmd.exe, batch, powershell, start->run, whatever)**

```
osk
```

Opens the on-screen-keyboard which has several "checkboxes" such as shift, ctrl, alt, capslock keys
Similar to the xgc answer, and inspired by the SmileBASIC answer screenshot.

Answer (score 8):

## TI-Basic, 15 bytes

```
While 1:Shade(0,9:Input :ClrDraw:Input :End
```

Fairly straightforward. The checkbox covers approximately 40% of the screen and alternates between black and white. When checked, the screen will look something like this:

> [image: screen]

Answer (score 7):

## Octave, <s>36</s> 20 bytes

```
uicontrol('sty','c')
```

Thanks to @LuisMendo  saved 16 bytes!

Comment: `uicontrol('sty','c')` also works

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! 1/2 byte counts saved!

Answer (score 7):

## Excel VBA, <sub><s>38</s> <s>32</s> <s>31</s></sub> 29 Bytes

Immediates Window function that inserts a checkbox of height=9 and width=9, at the cell `A1` on the first sheet of the active Excel VBA project

```vb
Sheet1.CheckBoxes.Add 0,0,9,9
```

-6 Thanks to pajonk for replacing `[A1],[A1],9,9` with `0,0,9,9`

-1 for replacing `Sheets(1)` with `[Sheet1]`

-2 for realizing the above was stupid and using `Sheet1` instead

Comment: Seems that `1,1,9,9` as arguments works as well.

Comment: You dont need the `Sheet(1).`, you can run this quickly enough in Excel but `CheckBoxes` is inherint to the active sheet

Comment: @Mr.Burns I have checked into this, but without directly referencing any Worksheet object, the `CheckBoxes.Add` method throws an error stating "Object Required"

Comment: @TaylorScott You are correct, I put the code in a sheet module rather than a normal module .. My mistake xD

Answer (score 7):

## SmileBASIC, 49 bytes

```
@L
O=T
TOUCH OUT T,,
X=T<O!=X
KEY 1,""[X]GOTO@L
```

`` and `` are an empty box and a checked box in SB's font.
Toggle the checkbox by touching the screen (the closest thing to clicking with a mouse)

[image]
[image]

## Cheating answers:

#### 0 bytes:

(the on-screen keyboard has buttons that act like checkboxes, such as the caps lock and insert keys)

#### 14 bytes:

```
EXEC"SYS/SBGED
```

Opens up the built in graphics editor, which has multiple checkbox-like buttons

Comment: This is just brilliant, though I don't really understand what the 4th line is doing. Could you explain?

Comment: `T<O` is true when you stop touching the screen, and `!=` is used as a logical XOR. `X=X XOR (O && !T)`

Answer (score 7):

## [KV Lang](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html), 8 bytes

```
CheckBox
```

[image]

---

assuming a really basic Python environment for kv lang to even run:

```
from kivy.app import runTouchApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
runTouchApp(Builder.load_string('CheckBox'))
```

This works basically because `CheckBox` is a Kivy widget included in a [`kivy.Factory`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.factory.html) as each widget from the standard library.

That simple string creates an instance of [`CheckBox`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.checkbox.html) and because of `runTouchApp` expecting a widget to run I can use `Builder.load_string`.

The background of `load_string` handles basically every kv string and if there is a single instance of a widget defined (e.g. `CheckBox`), then it is elevated to a **root** widget position, for example:

```
Application
    openGL Window
        root widget(mostly layout)
            main tree
            and some widgets
            ...
```

Answer (score 7):

### C#, <s>124</s> 120 bytes

saved 4 bytes thanks to grabthefish.

[image: checkbox checked and not checked]
note: because of edits, the picture doesn't exactly represent what the code makes, the "checkBox1" isn't displayed with the current code.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;class P{static void Main(){var a=new Form();a.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());a.ShowDialog();}}
```

ungolfed:

`using System.Windows.Forms;
class P{
  static void Main(){
    var a=new Form();
    a.Controls.Add(new CheckBox());
    Application.Run(a);
    a.ShowDialog();
  }
}`

Comment: If you didn't find anything about this on meta, **ask** about this on meta.

Comment: You can get rid of the spaces in `var a = new Form();`.

Comment: @Qwerp-Derp I removed them for counting, I just pasted the wrong thing, thanks.

Comment: you could use `a.ShowDialog();` to save a few bytes

Comment: thanks @grabthefish, though c# still loses to java :(

Comment: `a.Controls.Add(new CheckBox())` => `new CheckBox(){Parent=a}`

Comment: Let's discuss byte count: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11650/32091.

Answer (score 6):

## Ruby with Shoes, 16 characters

```ruby
Shoes.app{check}
```

Sample output:
[image: checkbox created with Ruby]

Answer (score 6):

## Powershell v5+, 94 Bytes

```
($a=[Windows.Forms.Form]::new()).Controls.Add([Windows.Forms.Checkbox]::new());$a.ShowDialog()
```

[image] [image]

This is pretty terrible, but I can't get the statements any shorter with either `Add-Type` or `using namespace` - and the variable is required, since I need to reuse the object to show the form, and `Controls.Add()` returns nothing usable.

`ShowDialog` is required on my system to have the box be interactive after running this command, otherwise the form is frozen.

also `System.Windows.Forms.Form` can only be shortened to `Windows.Forms.Form` before (at least my own) system stops auto completing it in a fresh session.

Comment: Nice! Might want to add that this requires version 5+.

Comment: @briantist updated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

### HTML with JavaScript, <s>46</s> <s>33</s> 28 bytes

```
<body onclick=innerHTML^=1>0
```

v2

```
<body onclick=this.innerHTML^=1>0
```

v1

```
<body onclick=t=this;t.innerHTML=t.e=!t.e||''>
```

This is a variant on @ElPedro's answer: [Create a Checkbox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109155/create-a-checkbox/109167#109167) . Got down to 28 bytes with the help of @Albert Renshaw It could be further reduced, but that would make it identical to [Create a Checkbox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109155/create-a-checkbox/109295#109295)

The whole application area is clickable. It will display `0` in the `off` state and `1` in the `on` state. Try it out at https://jsbin.com/nuhetiyocu/1/edit

Comment: Here's a neat variation at 39 bytes. `<body onclick=t=this;t.innerHTML^=t?1:0` The 16 pixel rule between state change is up for debate though.

Comment: 38 `<body onclick=this.innerHTML^=this?1:0`

Comment: 36 `<body onclick=this.innerHTML^=1+this`

Comment: Nice on 33! That's a great solution hhahah

Comment: Oh no with your help I'm down on 33 already :)

Comment: I dont think I can beat that lol

Comment: 28 `<body onclick=innerHTML^=1>0`

Comment: Now that there's always a value inside the container, it could be changed from the `body` to a different element. But I just noticed that would make it identical to another answer http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109155/create-a-checkbox/109295#109295 so I'm just leaving it as is

Comment: I always feel so original here until I see another answer in the same thread identical to my code  hahaha

Comment: Got a javascript solution down to 24 bytes now, different approach completely than what we were doing. http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/111422/16513

Answer (score 5):

## [Operation Flashpoint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Flashpoint:_Cold_War_Crisis) scripting language, 273 bytes

**To show the checkbox:**

```
createDialog"b"
```

**But first it must be defined:**

Save the following to a file named `description.ext` in the mission folder:

```
class b{idd=999;movingEnable=1;class controls{class c{idc=457;x=0.1;y=0.1;w=0.1;h=0.1;text="";action="if(ctrlText 457=={})then{ctrlSetText[457,{V}]}else{ctrlSetText[457,{}]}";type=1;style=2;colorText[]={1,1,1,1};font="tahomaB36";sizeEx=0.1;}}}
```

**The checkbox in action:**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

## Pug, 20 bytes

```
input(type=checkbox)
```

Comment: Besides which I count is as 23. If you remove the quotes it still works on Firefox and Chrome (can't test on IE) and would come in at 21 in which case I would consider it an improvement on the example and therefore valid.

Comment: @heonlygusti - indeed but without the quotes I would have upvoted :-) btw, the downvote wasn't me.

Comment: I would have up-voted if it wasn't for those quotes, which are not needed.

Comment: @theonlygusti not at all. Give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

### VBA (Word), <s>74</s> 57 bytes

-17 thanks to Taylor Scott

```
Sub a()
f = a.FormFields.Add(Selection.Range, 71)
End Sub
```

Filename of the document should be a.

Comment: You can replace the `wdFieldFormCheckBox` with `71` (the integer value of the `wdFieldFormCheckBox` constant) for a savings of 17 bytes

Comment: I think you can remove the newlines for -2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Clojure, <s>201</s> <s>195</s> <s>145</s> 127 bytes

```clj
(ns c(:require[quil.core :as q]))(def a(atom nil))(q/defsketch b :draw #(q/background(if@a 0 99)):mouse-clicked #(swap! a not))
```

-6 bytes by getting rid of the need for `m/fun-mode`.

-50 bytes by removing the `:setup` and `:size` options, since they are defaultable and unnecessary in non-`fun-mode`. Also removed the unnecessary import for middleware.

-18 bytes thanks to @ASCII-only. Changed to "smaller" colors, and removed an unnecessary space before the dereference operator (`@`).

Creates a [Quil](http://quil.info/) sketch (a Clojure library that provides a layer over Processing), therefore, this requires the Quil library to run.

```clj
(ns bits.golf.checkbox
  (:require [quil.core :as q]))

; Mutable global variable to hold the toggle state
(def a (atom nil))

(q/defsketch b
         ; Draw the background color to be either black or red depending on the toggle state.
         :draw #(apply q/background (if @a [0 0 0] [255 0 0]))

         ; Negate the state on mouse click
         :mouse-clicked #(swap! a not))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can't you replace 255 with 99? Also I'd try removing spaces before/after symbols and seeing if it still works

Comment: @ASCII-only yes, I could. It made a rant ugly color though iirc, and for some reason I prioritized that at the time. And no, this is as much space as I can remove unfortunately.

Comment: @ASCII-only The problem is symbols can contain almost any character, so really the only "safe neighbours" that you can remove spaces around are any kind of bracket, or quotes. Luckily this is a lisp to the former is pretty prevalent.

Comment: Hmm maybe `[0 0 99]` then? (some kind of dark blue)

Comment: @ASCII-only Actually, I think I can drop the 0s now that I think about it. I think Quil auto pads the front with 0s if the vector is to short. If I remember latest I'll fix it up. Thanks for getting me thinking.

Comment: Yeah, `(ns c(:require[quil.core :as q]))(def a(atom nil))(q/defsketch b :draw #(q/background(if@a 0 99)):mouse-clicked #(swap! a not))` works,  I just read the [docs](http://quil.info/api/color/setting), looks like it doesn't autopad, but it uses the value as a grayscale value. (Plus `@a` doesn't need a space before it)

Comment: @ASCII-only Thanks for the suggestions! I was occupied by the color channel challenge (and work) all day today. I'll try to incorporate your changes tomorrow.

Answer (score 3):

## [AutoIt](http://autoitscript.com/forum), 78 Bytes

```
GUICreate(0)
GUISetState(GUICtrlCreateCheckbox(0,0,0))
Do
Until GUIGetMsg()=-3
```

Opens a maximized window that can be closed like any other windows window. The maximization and ... on-top-ness is a side effect of the golfing.

[image]

Comment: How would I run this on Linux?

Comment: @wat `wine AutoIt3.exe script.au3`, where the `script.au3` file contains this code.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, 62 bytes

```
from tkinter import*
a=Tk()
Checkbutton(a).pack()
a.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 19 bytes

```
"<Ξ♠ΐ♠type=Ξ\t5δbox>
```

Replace `\t` with a tab literal and `♠` with `0x06`. [Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=IjzOngbOkAZ0eXBlPc6eBDXOtGJveD4)

```
"<Ξ♠ΐ♠type=Ξ\t5δbox>
"...................   string containing...
 <                     "<"
  Ξ♠ΐ♠                 compressed for "input "
      type=            "type="
           Ξ\t5δ       compressed for "CHECK"
                box    "box"
                   >
```

This displays a checkbox to the output element.

Answer (score 3):

### Slim, 21 Bytes

```
input type="checkbox"
```

[Try it here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WRyKma)

So yeah. One of slim's major features is that < and > characters are not there. So basically, I get 2 bytes less than the creator of the question!

Comment: HTML still beats it though :) http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109189/44888

Comment: remove quotes for better points

Comment: @wat It seems that's not allowed in Slim

Comment: @Metoniem That's excessively ironical.

Answer (score 3):

## Bash + zenity, 31

```
zenity --checklist --column a a
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## Bash (+yad), 23 bytes

**Golfed**

```bash
yad --form --field :chk
```

> YAD is a program that will display GTK+ dialogs, and return (either in the return code or on standard output) the users input. This
>          allows you to present information, and ask for information from the user, from all manner of shell scripts.

Yad is available in Debian and Ubuntu repositories (and probably others).

**Demo**

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### C#, 814 bytes

Out of interest I decided to see how many bytes it would take to use a console application in C# using the mouse to change the checked state. There is no built in support so you have to use unmanaged code and it get's very long, very fast. There might be room for improvement but it's never going to be short.

Note: It does seem to change the checked state when the mouse is pressed and is moved at the same time. But seeing as this is never going to compete I decided to leave that be as a quirk.

```cs
using System;using System.Runtime.InteropServices;class P{static void Main(){int m=0,n=0,c=0;var h=GetStdHandle(-10);GetConsoleMode(h,ref m);SetConsoleMode(h,m&=~64);new System.Threading.Thread(()=>{for(;;){var r=new[]{new r()};ReadConsoleInput(h,r,1,ref n);Console.Clear();if(r[0].e==2&&r[0].m.s==1)Console.BackgroundColor=++c%2<1?0:(ConsoleColor)1;}}).Start();}[StructLayout((LayoutKind)2)] struct r{[FieldOffset(0)]public int e;[FieldOffset(4)]public m m;}struct m{int p;public int s;}[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int h);[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr h,ref int m);[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr h,int m);[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]static extern bool ReadConsoleInput(IntPtr h,[Out]r[]r,int l,ref int n);}
```

And the formatted version:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

class P
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int m = 0, n = 0, c = 0;

        var h = GetStdHandle(-10);
        GetConsoleMode(h, ref m);
        SetConsoleMode(h, m &= ~64);

        new System.Threading.Thread(() =>
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                var r = new[] { new r() };
                ReadConsoleInput(h, r, 1, ref n);

                Console.Clear();
                if (r[0].e == 2 && r[0].m.s == 1)
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ++c % 2 < 1 ? 0 : (ConsoleColor)1;
            }
        }).Start();
    }

    [StructLayout((LayoutKind)2)]
    struct r
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int e;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public m m;
    }

    struct m
    {
        int p;
        public int s;
    }

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int h);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr h, ref int m);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr h, int m);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool ReadConsoleInput(IntPtr h, [Out]r[] r, int l, ref int n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## Java 1.4+, 104 bytes

```
import java.awt.*;interface g{static void main(String[]a){new Frame(){{add(new Checkbox());show();}};}}
```

-13 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen.

[image]

## Groovy, 67 bytes

```
import java.awt.*;{new Frame(){{add(new Checkbox())setVisible(1)}}}
```

Comment: Does `!0` work instead of `1>0`? It does in groovy.

Comment: The exact same thing is `68` bytes in groovy excluding `main method signature` and ending `;`.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur in groovy it'd just be `setVisible(1)`. In Java 8 it works; in all versions of java though, that is not valid syntax.

Comment: Oh okay. I just tried executing the groovy code (V. 2.4.7), I got EOF error. This works though - `import java.awt.*;new Frame(){{add(new Checkbox());setVisible(!0)}}` (67 bytes)

Comment: Ah, you're right. It was treating the `.*{` as a vectorized closure on `java.awt` so the `;` is required.

Comment: That closure won't execute - Error-`Ambiguous expression could be either a parameterless closure expression or an isolated open code block`. Also, `1` won't evaluate to true. It raises `MethodMissing exception`.

Comment: @GurupadMamadapur it ***is*** a parameter-less closure, it does run but I don't have to add `x=` and `x()` as per a sandbox discussion. But you're right about `!0` vs `1`. If you want it to run, surround the closure with `(<closure>)()`.

Comment: For your Java answer, you are using `main` but it's not in a class so I'm not sure how it would work... Also you can use `String[]a` instead of `String[] args`

Comment: Uh, you need to wrap the java code in a class, like `interface g{ ... }` (interface because that will let you drop `public` from `public static void main`

Comment: java: `javac` says: `reached end of file while parsing`. there is a closing bracket missing

Comment: Spaces ... >_< ... `String[] args`=>`String[]args`. And is it possible to change the name of the argument array?

Comment: This can be `import java.awt.*;interface g{static void main(String[]a){new Frame(){{add(new Checkbox());show();}};}}` instead (**103 bytes**). And I don't know Groovy, but maybe it also has a `show()` method?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen only valid in 1.8, invalid modifiers for versions below 1.8.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Oh, didn't knew `show()` was that new. Well, you can still golf `String[] args` to `String[]a`.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen made a mistake, had the wrong JRE loaded, you're right show is fine.

Answer (score 3):

## CSS, 46

Assumes a minimal HTML document, not unlike [this CSS Hello World submission](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/55570/31936).

This one avoids the extra "X" of the old 42 char solution, making it conform with the rules.

NOTE: Seems to only work in Firefox (51.0.1)

```css
* :after{content:'X'}*:active :after{all:unset
```

## CSS, 42 (old solution)

```css
:after{content:'X'}:active:after{all:unset
```

Comment: Not switching state by click, but switches to other state while muose button is pressed.

Comment: @Qwertiy, which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 56 on Windows 7 x64. Anyway, I expect it to be in any browser as `:active` should work only while mouse button is down. What browser do you use with the other result?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Firefox, as was clearly stated above.

Comment: Checked at my Firefox 52.0 beta 9 x32 - absolutely the same results as in Chrome. By the way, 42-byte solution has 3 states intead of 2: both Xs are visible, only the fisrst X is visible and both X are invisible. What OS are you using?

Comment: @Qwertiy That's why it's labeled the "old solution" :) I'm using macOS 10.12.3, and with Firefox 51.0.1 both solutions switch their state with a click – unlike how Chrome behaves.

Answer (score 2):

### [P5.js](https://alpha.editor.p5js.org/) <s>35</s> 26 bytes

<s>`function setup(){createCheckbox()}`</s>

not really fun, but it works.

```
setup=s=>createCheckbox()
```

-9 bytes thanks to Kritixi

Comment: `setup=s=>createCheckbox()` is shorter

Answer (score 2):

## FLTK, 48 characters

```fltk
Function{}{}{Fl_Window{}{}{Fl_Check_Button{}{}}}
```

Sample run:

```fltk
bash-4.3$ fluid -c checkbox.fl 

bash-4.3$ fltk-config --compile checkbox.cxx 
g++ -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng16 -g -O2 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_THREAD_SAFE -D_REENTRANT -o 'checkbox' 'checkbox.cxx' -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -lfltk -lX11

bash-4.3$ ./checkbox
```

Sample output:

[image: checkbox using FLTK]

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>151</s> 139 bytes

This is a longer approach than @satibel his answer, but it's completely different and doesn't require a form. Since I couldn't comment about if I could use key presses instead of mouse clicks (not enough rep.) I'm not 100% sure this is allowed, so let me know!

**EDIT**: Managed to lose 12 bytes thanks to some of my own improvements, and some are thanks to @TheLethalCoder

### Golfed

```
using c=System.Console;class p{static void Main(){for(int _=1;;_++){c.ReadKey();_%=2;c.BackgroundColor=(System.ConsoleColor)_;c.Clear();}}}
```

### Ungolfed

```
using System;
class p
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int _ = 0;
        for (int _=1;;_++)
        {
            Console.ReadKey(); //Wait for user input
            _%=2; //Prevent integer from overflowing at some point
            Console.BackgroundColor = (System.ConsoleColor)_; //Set Console background color to either 0 (black) or 1 (darkblue) depending on if our integer is even
            Console.Clear(); //Clear console window to get rid of input. This also causes the whole console window to change color
        }
    }
}
```

I know it's kind of tricky since it works with keypresses rather than mouseclicks, so let me know if that's allowed. If it's not, I'll happily remove my answer, or write a new one instead!

Comment: You can do it using mouse clicks but the code get's really long

Comment: Very very long in fact: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/109383/38550

Comment: @TheLethalCoder That's an amazing answer. I knew it was possible, but I didn't even dare to try.. GG to you sir! (Can't comment on other answers than my own yet, sorry)

Comment: Amazing that you can do it (I did a lot of googling and then hacking on the result to get it to work and be "short"). Just not amazing with how long it is! And no worries keep posting good answers and you will get there.

Comment: Improvement points (untested on length but should save you bytes): `using c = System.Console;` instead of `using System;` and then do `c.ReadKey();` etc, the `_++;` and `_%=2;` can be combined using post increment to `++_%=2;` (I think that should work although I haven't tested), `< 1` instead of `== 0`, Might be able to assign `_` on the `BackgroundColor` line but you'd have to experiment with it.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Oh hey, that's interesting. Let me try a few of those! I thought of `using c=System.Console;` but figured it was longer than writing `Console` 3 times.. Only I forgot I could then remove `using System;`

Answer (score 2):

## Vim: 13 <s>Bytes</s> Keystrokes

```
iq<Esc>:nm a g??<CR>
```

Press `a` and toggle between `q` and `d` (feels like a lever to me ...)

Explanation:

```
 iq<Esc>   " insert a q char
 nm a      " create a normal mapping toggled by a
 g??       " rot13 the current line, q -> d -> q ...
 <CR>      " validate the mapping
```

Comment: The checkbox has to be activated by the mouse, not the keyboard. I think you can do `:nm <LeftMouse> g??` instead

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript, <s>24</s> <s>23</s> 21

```
for(i=0;;)alert(i=!i)
```

```
i=0;while(1)alert(i=!i)
```

```
i=0;while(1)alert(++i%2)
```

**WARNING: Might cause you to have to force-quit your browser**

This one is a neat solution because it actually is not a check box and has none of the logic of a check box, but on the surface behaves very similar to a check box (toggling change of state on button press) due to exploiting the action-based delay in javascript alerts, and meets all of the criteria of rules defined in the challenge.

Try it here **(*Might cause you to have to force-quit your browser)**

```html
<script>for(i=0;;)alert(i=!i)</script>
```

Comment: Wow, this is clever. Usage of text as an image, I like it.

Answer (score 2):

## C (Win32 Console application), <s>143</s> 131 bytes

```
#include<windows.h>
main(){MSG m;for(CreateWindow("button","",1<<28|3,0,0,8,80,0,0,0,0);GetMessage(&m,0,0,0);DispatchMessage(&m));}
```

Answer (score 2):

## Red, 11 bytes

```
view[check]
```

The above code was rejected by SE as too short for a post, hence this addendum

Answer (score 1):

## Java, 69 bytes

```
a->{a.removeAll();a.add(new java.awt.Checkbox());a.setVisible(1>0);};
```

Just a not-so-self-explanatory `Consumer<Frame>`. It takes a `Frame`, removes everything in it, puts a checkbox, and then makes sure the `Frame` is displayed.

Comment: OP specified a program, not a function.

Comment: Java 8 is also important specification here.

Comment: @Pavel [Restricting to just programs requires explicitly specifying "full program" rather than just "program"](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/6912/12012)

Comment: What's your justification for being able to take a `Frame` as input?

Answer (score 1):

## [Coding](https://molarmanful.github.io/codinglang/), 21 bytes

```
>input(checkbox)@type
```

Finally a perfect time to use this language!

Answer (score 1):

## Racket, 98 bytes

```rkt
#lang racket/gui
((λ(f)(new check-box%[parent f][label""])(send f show #t))(new frame%[label""]))
```

At least I have a few bytes on the Clojure answer!

Answer (score 1):

## VBA, 42 bytes

```
ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes.Add(1,1,8,8).Select
```

Best I could get with this!

Answer (score 1):

### Emacs Lisp, 58

```
(and(widget-create'checkbox)(use-local-map widget-keymap))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## VB.NET, 67 (program) + 37 (additional switches) = 104

## VB.NET Windows Forms Application, 67 chars

```
Class F
Inherits Form
Dim C=New CheckBox With{.Parent=Me}
End Class
```

Compile it with

```
vbc.exe *.vb /main:F /imports:System.Windows.Forms
```

Not using `/target:winexe` switch. Assume that additional console is ok.

[image: Screenshot]

PS: [Question about byte count.](//meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11650/32091)

Comment: Nice. I don't think you need the `Inherits Form` if you specify you're using `Windows Form Application`.

Comment: @obarakon, but I don't specify that. That's just a file, not the part of solution. In case of winforms solution I wouldn't write `main` and `imports` switches by myself.

Comment: I get the desired form+checkbox just running `Class F Dim C=New CheckBox With{.Parent=Me} End Class` in an empty WFA project.

Comment: @obarakon, let's discuss byte count: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11650/32091. By the way, in case of winforms app you have partial class because of designer.

Answer (score 1):

## JQuery, 50 Bytes

```
$("<input type=checkbox>").appendTo(document.body)
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

## SAS, 145

```
proc pmenu catalog=work.c;menu m;item i dialog=d;dialog d '&1';text #1 @1 'A';checkbox #2 @1 'B';run;quit;%window w menu=work.c.m '';%display w;
```

This creates and displays a menu with an item that opens a dialogue box with a checkbox. It might be possible to golf it further, but I'm reluctant to try as this has already led to several crashed sessions :(

Answer (score 0):

### C# (Windows Form Application), 82 bytes

```
using System.Windows.Forms;class F:Form{public F(){Controls.Add(new CheckBox());}}
```

*Saved bytes thanks to @Qwertiy*

[image]

Comment: Full program, not a function.

Comment: Why do you need namespace? And partial class?

Comment: Let's discuss byte count: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/11650/32091.

Answer (score 0):

### C++ with SFML, 401 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to Zacharý

```cpp
#include<SFML\Graphics.hpp>
#include<cassert>
using namespace sf;int main(){RenderWindow w(VideoMode(300,300),"");Texture a,b;assert(a.loadFromFile("a.png")&&b.loadFromFile("b.png"));Sprite p(a),q(b);bool c=0;while(w.isOpen()){Event e;while(w.pollEvent(e)){if(e.type==Event::Closed)w.close();if(e.type==Event::MouseButtonPressed)c=!c;}w.clear(Color::White);if(c)w.draw(q);else w.draw(p);w.display();}}
```

Screenshot of the boxes :

Checked :

[image: Checked checkbox]

And unchecked :

[image: Unchecked checkbox]

This uses the SFML library
The checkbox changes state on a `sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed` event ( left click, right click, middle click... )

If you want to test, after the creation of the render window, you may want to set the framerate limit to 60 fps ( using the line `w.setFramerateLimit(60)` ), so your computer won't burn.

This requires 2 checkboxes images in the directory where the app runs ( `a.png` and `b.png` ). For the reason it uses images, i don't know if my answer is invalid ( standard loophole ? ), but since it's needed to do graphic output...

Comment: `a.loadFromFile("a.png") && b.loadFromFile("b.png")` => `a.loadFromFile("a.png")&&b.loadFromFile("b.png")`. `if (e.type`=>`if(e.type`. Does your code editor auto-format or something?

Comment: Forgot one... `VideoMode(300, 300)` => `VideoMode(300,300)`

Comment: @Zacharý Yes, it format every new semi colon.

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript, 14 bytes

`alert(alert())`

In most browsers, opening two alerts causes a checkbox to be added to the second that asks whether the user wants to keep allowing alerts.

[image]

I don't see anything in the rules that means it's not ok to first have a button that the user has to push before seeing the checkbox.

Comment: Actually the question's owner [explained in a comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/109155/create-a-checkbox/109240#comment265867_109155): “the checkbox should show up right away”. Hence the earlier `alert(alert())` and `alert(alert(1));` answers were deleted. ☹

Comment: Bah, comments. Rules should go in the rules.

Answer (score 0):

### SVG, 79 characters

```
<svg><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><input type="checkbox"/></body>
```

Yes, there is a closing tag missing, but FireFox and Chrome display it ok.

Answer (score 0):

## [Funky 2](https://github.com/tehflamintaco/funky2), 83 Bytes

```coffee
withdraw withnewWindow(){whenonDraw{setColor(a,1)box(0,0,8,8)}whenonMouseDown a=!a}
```

#### Cleaned up and commented

```coffee
with draw{                  $# With the draw library
    with newWindow(){       $# Open a new window with the default parameters
        when onDraw{        $# Each draw frame of the window. This can't be placed in onMouseDown due to Funky2 Automatically clearing the window
            setColor(a,1)   $# Set the color to either Green or Yellow depending on if a is 1 or not (Set color automatically adds arguments)
            box(0,0,8,8)    $# Draw a box of size 8 by 8.
        }
        when onMouseDown{   $# When any mouse button is clicked
            a=!a            $# Set a to not a. Conveniently, setColor casts it's argument to a number, so this flips between 0 and 1.
        }
    }
}
```

#### Output

[image: tada]

Answer (score 0):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 34 bytes

Expressions(27 bytes):

```
min(x,y)<9
C=hsv(0,0,a)
a=1
```

(Make sure to select the color corresponding to `C` for `min(x,y)<9`, set the fill opacity for `min(x,y)<9` to 1, and make sure that the graph is on the default viewport.)

On-click statement(6 bytes):

```
a->1-a
```

(27+6 is 33 bytes, but I have to add one byte because of [this](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19316/scoring-desmos-equations?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment74833_19317).)

Clicking anywhere on the graph will switch the color of the graph from white to black and vice versa.

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ahvi3wntyp)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uhmiljbp0k)